# Оптимальный способ передачи переменной

Tags: golang

Есть некая очень большая строка и 2 функции, которые выводят эту строку:

```
main() {
    str := "Very long string"
    printValueStr(str)
    printPointerStr(&str)
}

// printValueStr() принимает строку и выводит её на экран
func printValueStr(str string) {
    fmt.Println(str)
}

// printPointerStr() принимает указатель на строку и выводит её значение
func printPointerStr(str *string) {
    fmt.Println(*str)
}
```

Можно ли утверждать, что передача этой строки по ссылке всегда гарантировано будет работать быстрее, чем передача по значению? То есть во время выполнения программы нам не нужно создавать в памяти независимую копию переменной. Мы не тратим на это ресурсы, а просто обращаемся к уже существующей переменной.

Или же с точки зрения оптимизации разницы нет?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В Go тип `string` [внутри представлен](https://go101.org/article/string.html) в виде структуры из 2-х значений - указатель на массив байт с данными строки и длина этого массива:

```
type _string struct {
    elements *byte // underlying bytes
    len      int   // number of bytes
}
```

Размер структуры 8 или 16 байт, в зависимости от разрядности.

Соответственно, когда вы передаёте строку по значению в функцию, происходит копирование только вот этой вот структуры, а не всей строки. Другими словами, вам нет никакой необходимости связываться с указателем на строку и какой бы большой ни была строка, всё и так работает быстро.

Comment: 8/12 int 4 байта.

Comment: @ヒミコ А выравнивание? https://go101.org/article/memory-layout.html